# How to use the elasticsearch regex query correctly?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am working on translating a Splunk query to Elasticsearch DSL. 
I want to check if a URL in the logs contains something like:

```
"script>" OR "UNION ALL SELECT"
```

Fair enough I thought, went to the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), and:

```
{
  "regexp": {
    "http.url": "script>"
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch (2.3) replies:

> "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "reason": "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [regexp]", 
>           "type": "search_parse_exception", 
>           "line": 2,

Could someone enlighten me please about these kinds of queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward mistake when starting out with the documentation. In the docs, we generally only show the raw query (and its parameters). Queries are either compound queries or leaf queries. `regexp` is an example of a leaf query.

However, that's not enough to actually send the query. You're missing a simple wrapper part of the DSL for *any* query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "http.url": "script>"
    }
  }
}
```

To use a compound query, the best way is to use the [`bool` compound query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

It has `must`, `must_not`, `should`, or `filter` and each accept an array of queries (or filters, which are just scoreless, cacheable queries). `should` is the `OR`-like aspect of it, but do read the docs on how it behaves when you add `must` alongside it. The gist is that `should` by itself is exactly like an `OR` (as shown below), but if you combine it with `must`, then it becomes completely optional without using `"minimum_should_match": 1`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "http.url": "script>"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "http.url": "UNION ALL SELECT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get that now. Sorry for the confusion. This query seems to work. It would be great if you could tell me how to apply OR logic to the queries as well. I didn't made that too explicit in my question though.

Comment: There you go. I took the liberty of changing `regexp` to `term`, which assumes **exact** match behavior.